# Deserializing as Map or List - Firebase Admin Java SDK

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, orm, firebase-admin

### Background

I have a somewhat new Firebase Realtime Database and I'm using the Firebase Admin Java SDK to run a few aggregations daily. These aggregations have worked for the past few days, but today I experienced an `Exception` stating

> Map while deserializing, but got a class java.util.ArrayList

The fields where I received this message map optional incrementing `Integers` to `Lists` of `Objects`. For example, I have

```
responses:
   4:
      someField: 'someValue',
      anotherField: 'anotherValue'
   6:
      someField: 'someValue',
      anotherField: 'anotherValue'
```

**Before you mark this as a duplicate, please read the question to see why it's unique.** There are other SO questions for this Exception, but they don't ask my question.

### Observation

Note how new data caused this `Exception` and not an invalid `ORM`, as it functioned with real data previously. I noticed the specific child where the `Exception` occurred had more keys than other children.

I am mapping the structure above as `Map<String, List<MyObject>> responses` (removed `MyObject` name and actual fields to make it less distracting). I assumed it would be better to use a `Map`, since the `List` could eventually only have values at indexes `567`, `568`, `569` for example.

**I have a hunch that today when there were a certain number of integer keys, the `Firebase Admin SDK` decided to recognize the `Map` as a List, since it really is a List.**

Fair enough, so I modified all of my code to make `List<List<MyObject>> responses`. But this caused the `Exception`

> Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

I noticed this occurred sooner in the execution of my program on `responses` with fewer keys.

### Question

**What determines if the object is mapped as a List or Map in the circumstances? Was my assumption about the transition with the number of keys valid?** Of course, there is always a chance something was invalid in my structure, but it was updated by another program and I triple-checked.

Comment: Please show your code that performs the query and what it expects from the resulting snapshot, and the contents of the database that you're querying.  It's difficult to piece together everything without code.

Comment: I can add the code and database when I get back to my computer, but the query simply uses a single value get and .getValue(Response.class). I added the necessary database contents (db too large to add all now). I was hoping for somebody to answer the conceptual question.

Comment: "if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array".. From https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Without seeing your code and database structure it's hard to answer your question.